# How to run weblogic with two apex versions?

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracle-apex

Running WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0 on RHEL 7.5.
In ./user_projects/applications/ApexDom there are two directories plsapex1 and plsapex2 with the associated war-files.

plsapex1 points to a database with APEX 18.2, plsapex 2 to a database with APEX 5.0.4

the apex resource files are in
./user_projects/domains/ApexDom/resources
   /apex
   /apex-5.0.4

Calling an application under /plsapex1 (18.2) works. Calling an application under /plsapex2 (5.0.4) shows the message: "The files for version 18.2.0.00.12 have been loaded, but 5.0.4.00.12 is expected"

Is it possible to run Weblogic with 2 APEX versions?

Comment: It appears you need two datasources. Datasource1 pointing to APEX 18.2 and datasource2 pointing to APEX 5.0.4. Is this how you have it setup ?

Comment: I guess I should ask if the error is related to the files or the database ?

Comment: @souser: plsapex1 and plsapex2 are the two datasource. The error seems to be related not to the database, but to the missing old apex 5.0.4-files, that are in /i